# Consider a paint-drying situation in which drying time for a test specimen...

Tags: probability, statistics, normal-distribution

> Consider a paint-drying situation in which drying time for a test specimen is normally distributed with $\sigma = 8$. The hypotheses $H_0: \mu = 73$ and $H_a: \mu < 73$ are to be tested using a random sample of $n = 25$ observations.
>
> How many standard deviations (of $X$) below the null value is $x = 72.3$?

I know that I might need the equation $z = \frac{x-u}{\sigma/\sqrt{n}}$ and I think I need to solve for standard deviation.

Is this the correct approach? Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Your question has a potential confusion between the *standard deviation*
$\sigma = 8$ of a single drying time and the *standard error* $\sigma/\sqrt{25} = 8/5 = 1.6$ of the average $\bar X$ of
$n = 25$ drying times.

The $Z$-statistic $Z=\frac{\bar X - \mu_0}{\sigma/\sqrt{25}} = \frac{72.3-73}{1.6}
= -0.2625$ indicates that the sample mean $\bar X$ is $-0.2625$ of a standard error below the hypothetical mean $\mu_0.$ (Not a surprising result.)

One would not reject $H_0$ at the 5% level of
significance because $Z$ is not below the critical $-1.645$ (which cuts 5% of
the area from the lower tail of a standard normal distribution).